# How to show toast message after a period of time in android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am showing toast message after every 20 seconds from current time but if I going out the app it is not working. Here is my code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    final static private long ONE_SECOND = 1000;
    final static private long TWENTY_SECONDS = ONE_SECOND * 20;

    PendingIntent pi;
    BroadcastReceiver br;
    AlarmManager am;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
                Toast.makeText(c, "Rise and Shine!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("Receive message in every five seconds", "message");
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("com.authorwjf.wakeywakey"));
        pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
                "com.authorwjf.wakeywakey"), 0);
        am = (AlarmManager) (this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));

        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                TWENTY_SECONDS, pi);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        am.cancel(pi);
        unregisterReceiver(br);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

My question is if the app is not running but still it can show toast message? How can it possible in android?

Comment: in onDestroy(), remove unregisterReceiver(br);. Or use service.

Comment: if I remove onDestroy() it show me error message. How to integrate service for this type of problems. Can you provide me some links or tutorials?

Comment: @divoom12: this way you will leak the broadcastreceiver

Comment: Why don't you register the `br` receiver in the Manifest?

Comment: I am using default BroadCastReceiver class. How do I register the default broadcastreceiver in menifest.

Answer (score 0):

you must create a Class Updater which contain a Handler

it will be executed periodically (you can define this periode) like that:

```
    import android.os.Handler;
    public class Updater {

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable mStatusChecker;
    final static private long TWENTY_SECONDS = 20000;
    private int UPDATE_INTERVAL = TWENTY_SECONDS;

    public Updater(final Runnable updater){
        mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updater.run();
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
            }
        };
    }

    public Updater(Runnable updater, int interval){
        this(updater);
        UPDATE_INTERVAL = interval;
    }

    public void startUpdates(){
        mStatusChecker.run();
    }

    public void stopUpdates(){
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);
    }}
```

than create a service "ServiceOn" :

```
    public class ServiceOn extends Service {

Updater updater = new Updater(new Runnable() {

    @Override 
    public void run() {

    // put your code here
    //  toast or what you want
    }});

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {       
        updater.startUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        updater.stopUpdates();
        super.onDestroy();
    }}
```

and finally in your activity you can call this service:

```
context.startService(new Intent(context, ServiceOn.class));
```

this will work for every 20 seconds even if the app stop running

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code i hope its working...

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    final Handler h=new Handler();
    final  Runnable r=new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Example OF Practicle 8",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 };

 Timer t=new Timer();
 t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        h.post(r);
     }
 },2000, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout

```
setTimeout( function(){ 
    toastr.clear(); // User to Clear the Toast Message Popup
}, 1000 ); // We can set our own time interval to disappear the popup
```

Hope it will help you